# Typescript specify string array or just empty array but not `any[ ]`

Tags: arrays, typescript

Got this basic problem:

```
let b:string[] = []
undefined
> b
[]
> b[0].split('')
```

Throws an error because `b[0]` won't store a string. Also `[ ]` is different from `[null]` or `[undefined]` as far as I understand.

And this isn't good enough `b:string[]|[]` because that makes it `any[]` afaik.

How do you specify either `string[]` or empty array `[ ]`?

Comment: If you make it as `Array<string | undefined>`, won't it solve the problem?

Comment: `string[]` already covers for empty array, unless I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: `Throws an error because b[0] won't store a string.` does not mean TypeScript throws an error, it means the JS it's transformed into (which in this case would be exactly the same code but with `:string[]` removed) is throwing an error.

Comment: @RicardoPortugal that would cause trouble because `string[ ]` would allow for string methods on each item, wouldnt it?

Comment: @Minsky yes, as you're declaring it as `string[]`. If you'd like e.g. for the list to also hold numbers, you'd do `let b: (string | number)[] = []`.

Comment: @RicardoPortugal yes but in this case it could end up being `[ ]` if I initialize it as let `a:string[ ] = [ ]` throwing an error. My point it that a is not a string array currently.

Comment: @Minsky as @Sergiu mentioned, that's a runtime problem. You always need to check for the presence of elements in the list, regardless of the types its holding. You could do something like:

`let chars = []; if (b.length) { chars = b[0].split(''); }`

Comment: @RicardoPortugal I see, then I confused that `number[], string[]...` would literally contain str or num, but they can just be empty..

Comment: At runtime, if you don't actually check, things like user input or API responses can be anything. TypeScript does absolutely nothing at runtime.

Comment: `string[] | []` is not `any[]`.  I'm not sure why you think an empty array cannot be a `string[]` just because the `0`-index is undefined; by that logic, the value `["hello", "there"]` cannot be a `string[]` because the element at index `2` is undefined.  If you want the compiler to warn you about possibly dereferencing `undefined` values that come out of an array or other indexed access, you might want to turn on the `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` compiler option as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/NBjQdN).  Does this approach meet your needs?  Let me know.

Comment: @jcalz Well, sorry if it is a dumb question but it would make sense to me, that typescript `string[ ] = [ ]` would error out because this array has length 1, and first item is undefined and not a string. This would produce errors down the stream. Now, you point out that arrays `['hello', 'there']` will be undefined on index 3, but it has length 2. It is not clear to me how far should I consider typescript realm, or JS realm.

Comment: You can verify for yourself in both TS and JS that `[]` has length 0, not 1.  There is no first item.  Compare to something like `["hello"]` which actually has length 1.  Maybe we’re talking past each other and I’m just not understanding you… could you explain where length 1 is coming from?

Comment: @jcalz I tried yesterday and it was 1. Now it is 0. Think I got lost now though. But thanks for getting me back on track.

Comment: So then does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NBjQdN) meet your needs where we turn on `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess`?  Just trying to figure out what, if any, answer you want to see here.

Answer (score 0):

```
  const c: [] | string[] = []; // either string array, or empty array
```

Also, in javascript, referring to array elements that are not defined returns `undefined` - it's the way javascript works.

Writing "safe" code while working with possibly undefined values might look like this

```
const c: string[] = [];

console.log((c[5] ?? '').split('.'));

// or

console.log(c[5]?.split('.'));
```